# Validating a string vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to search a string to make sure it does not contain a numbers followed by a comma followed by numbers and containing a dot and 2 decimal places, e.g. 32,000.00. At the moment, I have it searching to see if the string contains a dot only. How do I go about searching the criteria above?

```
Root_RefundAmount = Root_TaxDataSummary.SlvObject("RefundAmount").GetROProperty("text") 
refund = InStr(1,Root_RefundAmount,".")
If refund > 0 Then          
    pass
Else
   fail
End If
```

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a simple Regular Expression Test will provide you what you want:

```
Dim objRegEx, strValue

'Create Regular Expression object to parse the file
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\d+\,\d+\.\d{2}"

strValue = "e.g. 32,000.00."
MsgBox objRegEx.test(strValue)  '<- True

strValue = "e.g. 3200000."
MsgBox objRegEx.test(strValue)  '<- False
```

The above will result in a Boolean response (True/False).
Adapting it to your routine...

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\d+\,\d+\.\d{2}"

Root_RefundAmount = Root_TaxDataSummary.SlvObject("RefundAmount").GetROProperty("text") 
If Not objRegEx.test(Root_RefundAmount) Then          
    'Pattern NOT Found
Else
    'Pattern IS Found
End If
```

To explain the Pattern:

```
"\d+\,\d+\.\d{2}"
```

\d = Any Number 0 through 9...

"A numbers followed by a comma followed by numbers and containing a dot and 2 decimal places"{Assume you mean 2 Numbers}...  Depending on your input the above is much easier to look at but it will also match numbers such as 12345,12345.99 which may or may not be desirable.

If you need to be precise then you may want to consider the below Regex:

```
"\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*\.\d{2}"
```

This will match numbers from 0.00 to 999,999,999.99 etc in typical numeric format...

If you want to specifically look for numbers above 1,000 (With a Comma) Then change the Star '*' to a Plus '+' to mean One or More are Required...

```
"\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})+\.\d{2}"
```

Or for an even more specific Regex:

```
(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})(?:\,[0-9]{3})+\.[0-9]{2}
'OR
(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2})(?:\,\d{3})+\.\d{2}
```

For a little more info on Regular Expressions and the '\d' Character Class, Please take a look at the below links:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_9

Comment: That regex will not match `32,000.00`. See [Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dMWcM2UCr47Z2Mq4)

Comment: Closest regex I can get is `^[0-9]{1,3}\,(?:\,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$` and even that's not right.

Comment: @Lankymart Technically my Regex would match the '2,000.00' portion.  I added a '+' to the \d Character Class which would match all of it.  From what I gathered from the OP's question, they are just looking to make sure a number in a certain format does not exist within a value.  Did I miss read the question?

Comment: That latest regex, definitely closer but it won't match something like `11,456,001.00`. However this should `(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2})(?:\,[0-9][0-9]{2})+\.[0-9]{2}`

Comment: @Lankymart Good Catch.  Should be "[0-9]{3}" instead.  I edited my response and it matches that number properly.